# Slick Slider not showing up within Bootstrap5 Tab content

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, slick.js

I'm trying to use the slick slider with Bootstrap5 Nav,  somehow the slider is not showing up within the active tab content unless I resize the window. I've tried to arrange the sequence of embedded JavaScript, and the slider got broken instead.
It works fine with pure text but not slick slider, the problem seems to be JavaScript of Bootstrap and Slick.

Here's my code: https://codepen.io/HarperJ/pen/XWqrBem

Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-8">
      <ul class="nav solution_nav mb-5">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <button class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab_1" type="button"
                    role="tab" aria-selected="false">TAB 1</button>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <button class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab_2" type="button" role="tab"
                    aria-selected="false">TAB 2</button>
            </li>
        
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab_1" role="tabpanel">
            
            <div class="slider slider-for">
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1637779827592-1a6bc47d21b3?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzOTkyNzcwMg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85' alt=''>
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1638058393863-4ae0d0075635?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzOTkyNzcwMg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85' alt=''>
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1638588635868-cd8290af2266?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzOTkyNzc2OQ&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85' alt=''>
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1638058393863-4ae0d0075635?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzOTkyNzcwMg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85' alt=''>
            </div>
            <div class="slider slider-nav">
                <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1637779827592-1a6bc47d21b3?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzOTkyNzcwMg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85' alt=''>
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1638058393863-4ae0d0075635?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzOTkyNzcwMg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85' alt=''>
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1638588635868-cd8290af2266?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzOTkyNzc2OQ&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85' alt=''>
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1638058393863-4ae0d0075635?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzOTkyNzcwMg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85' alt=''>
            </div>
            
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_2" role="tabpanel">
            
            <div class="slider slider-for2">
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1659427219844-d45d5a49780d?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NjIwMjE3ODg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80' alt=''>
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1660508344047-d535438fc3fa?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NjIwMjE3ODg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80' alt=''>
      
            </div>
            <div class="slider slider-nav2">
                <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1659427219844-d45d5a49780d?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NjIwMjE3ODg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80' alt=''>
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1660508344047-d535438fc3fa?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NjIwMjE3ODg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80' alt=''>
      
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
/*     outline: 1px solid green; */
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

.solution_nav .nav-link {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    color: #ddd;
    padding: 16px 40px;
}
.solution_nav .nav-link.active{
  color: #343434;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #343434;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider-for').slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: false,
      fade: true,
      asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
  });
  $('.slider-nav').slick({
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      asNavFor: '.slider-for',
      dots: true,
      // centerMode: true,
      centerMode: false,
      focusOnSelect: true,
      dots: false,  
      arrows: false
  });
  
    $('.slider-for2').slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: false,
      fade: true,
      asNavFor: '.slider-nav2'
  });
  $('.slider-nav2').slick({
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      asNavFor: '.slider-for2',
      dots: true,
      // centerMode: true,
      centerMode: false,
      focusOnSelect: true,
      dots: false,  
      arrows: false
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach the slick to an event after the tab is shown, otherwise the element doesn't necessarily exists. The proper event is `shown.bs.tab`. I have set up an example to convey the idea. It isn't generalized enough, but it works.

```js
var did_init_tab_2 = false;

const tabEl = document.querySelector('[data-bs-target="#tab_2"]')
tabEl.addEventListener('shown.bs.tab', event => {
  if (did_init_tab_2) {
    return;
  }
  did_init_tab_2 = true;
  $('.slider-for2').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
  });
})



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider-for').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
  });


})
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*     outline: 1px solid green; */
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.solution_nav .nav-link {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  color: #ddd;
  padding: 16px 40px;
}

.solution_nav .nav-link.active {
  color: #343434;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #343434;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" integrity="sha512-yHknP1/AwR+yx26cB1y0cjvQUMvEa2PFzt1c9LlS4pRQ5NOTZFWbhBig+X9G9eYW/8m0/4OXNx8pxJ6z57x0dw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-8">
      <ul class="nav solution_nav mb-5">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <button class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab_1" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="false">TAB 1</button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <button class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab_2" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="false">TAB 2</button>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab_1" role="tabpanel">

          <div class="slider slider-for">
            <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1637779827592-1a6bc47d21b3?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzOTkyNzcwMg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85' alt=''>
            <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1638058393863-4ae0d0075635?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzOTkyNzcwMg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85' alt=''>
            <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1638588635868-cd8290af2266?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzOTkyNzc2OQ&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85' alt=''>
            <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1638058393863-4ae0d0075635?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzOTkyNzcwMg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85' alt=''>
          </div>


        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_2" role="tabpanel">

          <div class="slider slider-for2">
            <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1659427219844-d45d5a49780d?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NjIwMjE3ODg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80' alt=''>
            <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1660508344047-d535438fc3fa?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NjIwMjE3ODg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80' alt=''>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works! What if there are more than two contents to switch? 
Based on your code, can I make it like this? [my demo](https://codepen.io/HarperJ/pen/gOzOrZm)

Comment: Yes that works. The style of code can be changed so you Don't Repeat Yourself, but the result is the same: initialize each carousel once its tab is shown for the first time.